# Is the LED-like device in the front of an Arduino flame sensor a photo transistor?

Tags: arduino, phototransistor

This is a common Arduino flame sensor found in the Elegoo 37 sensors kit V2.
Is the led in front of it a photo transitor?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, according to [this page](http://www.theorycircuit.com/arduino-flame-sensor-interface) it is often a [YG1006](https://www.velleman.eu/downloads/29/infosheets/vmp502_yg1006.pdf)